# Setting the App Icon (Xcode 7)

Tags: ios, xcode

I have looked around and none of the other topics I found have addressed the error I am getting with my App Icon. When I try to run my app, it gives the error:

The app icon set named "AppIcon" did not have any applicable content

I'm pretty sure this is because I don't have the .png file in the right place but I can't figure out where to put it. It is currently listed under the project file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go to `Images.xcassets` add in `AppIcon` all icons sizes as Image below.

This app [Prepo](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/prepo/id476533227?mt=12) can quick generate the files to help you.

[image: AppIcon]

Comment: Do you mean Assets.xcassets rather than Images.xcassets? Or is this the thing that I'm missing?

Comment: Usually is Images.xcassets by default, but you could use a different name. Check also if the file is your Project > Target > App Icons and Launch Images > Apps Icons Source

Comment: I'm still getting the same error... Project > Target > AppIcon (as it should) and Launch Images > App Icons Source > AppIcon.

Comment: You made sure you have added all sizes of icons?

Comment: I have an image in all six slots, yes.

Comment: Would it cause this error if they were not formatted to the right sizes?

Comment: Ah! That was it. Note to anyone else who wants to do this, app icons must be scaled properly for each different platform. Prepo does this well.