# Name of iOS App Changed to AppIcon

Tags: ios, xcode7

I recently asked a question about how to change the icon of an app in Xcode 7 and I managed to do it:
[Setting the App Icon (Xcode 7)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34323081/setting-the-app-icon-xcode-7)
However, in doing this, the name of my app seems to have been changed to AppIcon (the name of a target of my project). Any ideas why this is or how I can change it back?

Comment: double-click slowly in the Project name and you can edit it

Comment: The project name isn't the problem. It is correct. The app is running with a name different from the project name.

Comment: i see.. please check your info.plist. look at the value of Bundle Display Name

Comment: It was at this: $(PRODUCT_NAME). I changed it to War and now the name on my phone is War but Xcode still says it is running AppIcon. Thanks for helping get the visible title right though.

Comment: how about your scheme? is it correct?

Comment: Where would I find that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98187/discussion-between-julie-and-ulthran).

Answer (score 0):

You can it easily

Can the bundle name (not bundle id) to your app name

and aslo change the product name

it will solve ur issue

Answer (score 0):

You should change `Bundle name` in `plist` file as: `${PRODUCT_NAME}`
Hope this could help.[image]

Comment: This is what was causing the problem in the first place. Read the comments.